# Ubuntu 14.04 Rebooting Not Working

Tags: 14.04, grub2, shutdown, reboot

When ever I reboot Ubuntu (not shutdown but reboot), my computer hangs. It hangs before grub even comes in to go to Ubuntu. I then have to manually do a hard shutdown and power it back on and it boots fine. If I shutdown Ubuntu the way your supposed everything works like it should. It is only when I reboot that I get this problem. I don't know where to look?

Comment: Did you tried to update anything?? The updates might be the problem If they are not installed correctly they are problematic with reboots.

Comment: Do you wait some time between shutdown and cold restart? If yes, it could also be a thermal issue. My laptop gets a entirely white screen when I boot/reboot it while it is warm (not even hot, maybe 40°C or so).

Comment: This was happening from day one of the install of Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm on a desktop computer where my computer is colder than my appartment

Comment: we are not alone :-)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/797544?comments=all
and the machine reboots at work today 3 times without a any problems
and now it hangs every time on reboot..no counter.. I power off the machine .. no change ..no sudo update today ..strange !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

At boot time choose to go to recovery mode in the GRUB menu.
Then choose to repair filesystems, when it finishes then reboot.

Now you'll see booting will be fine until sooner or later it'll happen again and then you've to repeat the procedure.

If you're a little more into tinkering with your computer try to install the newest kernel from: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

**Don't install a new kernel if you're not sure about how to cope with new problems that you might encounter after doing this.**

It did solve problems for me, however.